# Python: Keys disappearing from REDIS and expiration does not works properly

Tags: python, redis

I am running a Python web application on CloudLinux/Litespeed server.

Python version:3.9.12
Redis version: 4.4.0

Server has a lot of RAM and hardware resources.

My app is saving at REDIS many keys (1000/hour), almost all of them with expiration.
The problem is that at the time to retrieve the key, very frequently some the keys are no longer there, even if set to expire only after 180 days, and, in other cases, a key that should expire after 240 seconds, it stay there for hours or even for days. Even if the key is not set with expiration, sometimes it disappear too.
The problem does not affect all keys, but about 50% of them. Seems an intermittent problem.

The data center support insist the problem is not at REDIS because there are other users plugged in the same REDIS (sounds like running in promiscuous mode) and there are no complains.

This is my code:

```
import redis      # redis 4.4.0

running_environment = 'SERVER'

if running_environment == 'SERVER' or running_environment == 'DEV':
    utils_cache_redis = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)




def set_value_at_redis_with_expiration(key_name, key_life_at_redis__seconds, key_value):
    if running_environment == 'SERVER' or running_environment == 'DEV':
        life_at_redis_days = key_life_at_redis__seconds / 60 / 60 / 24
        life_at_redis_days_formatted = ("%.2f" % life_at_redis_days)
        key_life_at_redis__seconds = int(key_life_at_redis__seconds)
        try:
            utils_cache_redis.set(key_name, str(key_value))
            utils_cache_redis.expire(key_name, key_life_at_redis__seconds)
            logger.debug(f'Set value at REDIS. Key name: [{key_name}]. Key life: [{life_at_redis_days_formatted} days] ({key_life_at_redis__seconds} seconds). Key value: [{key_value}]')
        except:
            logger.critical(f'Error while setting at REDIS. Variable name [{key_name}], Key life: [{life_at_redis_days_formatted} days] ({key_life_at_redis__seconds} seconds).  Variable value [{key_value}]')
    else:
        logger.info('Cannot set value at REDIS because it is not running at SERVER')







def check_if_key_is_present_at_redis(key):
    if running_environment == 'SERVER' or running_environment == 'DEV':
        try:
            if utils_cache_redis.exists(key) == True:
                logger.debug(f'Key found at REDIS: [{key}]')
                return True
            else:
                logger.debug(f'Key NOT found at REDIS: [{key}]')
                return False
        except:
            logger.critical(f'Error testing if key [{key}] exists at REDIS')
            return False
    else:
        logger.warning(f'Cannot check if key [{key}] is present at REDIS because is not running at server')
        return False



set_value_at_redis_with_expiration('key_name_at_redis', 10000000, 'this is a test')

if check_if_key_is_present_at_redis('key_name_at_redis') == True:
    print('Key found at redis')
else:
    print('Key not found at redis')
```

Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: Don’t you want to expire the *key_name* rather than the value? `utils_cache_redis.expire(key_value…)`

Comment: @Mark you are right, there is a bug, the correct is expire the _key_name_  (I will edit the code in my question), but in fact this will not change too much as this problem was introduced yesterday, when I moved from `PSETEX` to `SET` + `EXPIRE` in a try to fix, but without success.

Comment: Main problem are the keys that disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found. Keys were disappearing because the REDIS was running in promiscuous mode, where multiple users had access to the same pool of REDIS keys (in the shared server). And likely somebody was deleting my keys.
The problem was fixed by segregating REDIS, preventing anybody else to access my keys at REDIS.